# Did NASA develop any crewed moon landing programs between Apollo and Constellation?

Tags: nasa, history, lunar-landing, constellation-program

I just assumed that NASA has always been developing some plan to get humans back on the moon since Apollo was cancelled. But while attempting to verify this, I found that this doesn't seem to be the case. So now I'm trying to understand during exactly which intervals was NASA making such an attempt? Of course, the last such attempt was Apollo 17 in 1972. And the current SLS program is the most recent such attempt. The only other one that I can find is the Constellation program of 2005-2009. Are there any others I'm missing? (Non-NASA attempts are welcome, though I know there are a bunch of those.)

Comment: The [Space Exploration Initiative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Exploration_Initiative) is definitely something worth looking into. It was proposed by George H.W. Bush. Initial plans was to stay on the Moon and Mars, and construct the Space Station Freedom. However, due to budget cuts and other things, that developed into the International Space Station.